# Overriding subclass methods with subclassed arguments?

Tags: scala, inheritance, overriding

How can I force base methods to take in the same specific subclass instance when overriden by a subclass?

i.e.:

```
abstract class Animal {
  def mateWith(that: Animal)
}

class Cow extends Animal {
  override def mateWith...?
}
```

Logically, a `Cow` should only be able to `mateWith` another `Cow`.  However, if I do `override def mateWith(that: Cow)`, this doesn't actually override the base class method (which I want it to, since I want to enforce its existence in the subclass).

I could check to make sure the other instance is of type Cow, and throw an exception if it isn't - is this my best option?  What if I have more animals?  I would have to repeat the exception-throwing code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
abstract class Animal[T <: Animal[T]] {
  def mateWith(that: T)
}

class Cow extends Animal[Cow] {
  override def mateWith(that: Cow) { println("cow") }
}

class Dog extends Animal[Dog] {
  override def mateWith(that: Dog) { println("dog") }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
scala> (new Cow).mateWith(new Cow)
cow

scala> (new Cow).mateWith(new Dog)
<console>:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Dog
 required: Cow
              (new Cow).mateWith(new Dog)
                                 ^
```

No exception-throwing code needed; the type system handles it for you at compile-time!

Comment: Sweet deal, Scala's convenient as heck!

Comment: I'm not so sure about "convenient," but expressive it is.

Comment: Thought I'd revisit this - this is known as [f-bounded-polymorphism](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded).