# Polymorphic Scala return type

Tags: scala, generics, polymorphism, return-type

I have an abstract Scala class `Base` which has subclasses `Derived1` and `Derived2`. `Base` defines a function f() which returns an object of the same type as its implementing class. So `Derived1.f()` returns `Derived1` and `Derived2.f()` returns `Derived2`. How do I write this in Scala?

Here is what I have come up with so far.

```
package com.github.wpm.cancan

abstract class Base {
  def f[C <: Base]: C
}

case class Derived1(x: Int) extends Base {
  def f[Derived1] = Derived1(x + 1)
}

case class Derived2(x: Int) extends Base {
  def f[Derived2] = Derived2(x + 2)
}
```

This gives the following compiler errors:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : com.github.wpm.cancan.Derived1
[error]  required: Derived1
[error]   def f[Derived1] = Derived1(x + 1)

type mismatch;
[error]  found   : com.github.wpm.cancan.Derived2
[error]  required: Derived2
[error]   def f[Derived2] = Derived2(x + 2)
```

This error message is confusing to me because I think `com.github.wpm.cancan.Derived1` should be the same as `Derived1` in this context.

Comment: The `Derived1` in `def f[Derived1]` is not a reference to `case class Derived1`, it's a type parameter for `def f ...`!

Comment: I think you can use the `override` keyword on methods to get what you want (but you must get rid of the type parameter).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Randall Schulz pointed out one of the reasons your current code doesn't work. It is possible to get what you want, though, with [*F*-bounded polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification):

```
trait Base[C <: Base[C]] { def f: C }

case class Derived1(x: Int) extends Base[Derived1] {
  def f: Derived1 = Derived1(x + 1)
}

case class Derived2(x: Int) extends Base[Derived2] {
  // Note that you don't have to provide the return type here.
  def f = Derived2(x + 2)
}
```

The type parameter on the base trait allows you to talk about the implementing class there—e.g. in the return type for `f`.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199254/overriding-subclass-methods-with-subclassed-arguments) is another example of use of that language feature

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this particular instance of F-bounded polymorphism is relatively well known as the Curiously Recursive Template/Type Pattern, and is used for the purpose of defining a function in a base type whose return value is polymorphic over subtypes in various places - for example, the Java definition of an Enum is class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>.

Comment: @Impredicative: I've always heard it referred to as the Curiously _Recurring_ Template Pattern, which is a little more meta.

Answer (score 8):

Just to add a small precision about (perfectly good) Travis Brown answer: It's not that `C` in `trait Base[C <: Base[C]]` let's you refer to the implementing class; it's just sticking to the convention of writing `subclass extends Base[subclass]` that let's you do so. There's no way that I know of to refer to this type. To clarify what I mean, this compiles

```scala
trait Base[C <: Base[C]] { def f: C }

case class Derived1(x: Int) extends Base[Derived1] {
  def f: Derived1 = Derived1(x + 1)
}
// a Derived2 where f returns Derived1!!
case class Derived2(x: Int) extends Base[Derived1] {
  def f = Derived1(x + 2)
}
```

Now, if all you're going to have as implementations of `Base` are case classes, you can get this right through a self-type bound:

```
trait Base[C <: Base[C]] { self: C => 
  def f: C 
}

case class Derived1(x: Int) extends Base[Derived1] {
  def f: Derived1 = Derived1(x + 1)
}
// a Derived2 where f returns Derived1!!
// this won't compile now
case class Derived2(x: Int) extends Base[Derived1] {
  def f = Derived1(x + 2)
}
```

Comment: I don't understand - why does the latter solution only work for case classes?

Comment: it will work if your `Base` hierarchy has just one level (which is true if they all are case classes)