# Scala trait same method and argument with different return types

Tags: scala

I am on Scala 2.10.2 and trying to define a trait like

```
trait Foo {
  def bar(a:String): String
  def bar(a:String): Int
}
```

Getting a compiler error `method a is defined twice`. What's the correct syntax?

Comment: As well as in Java, there is no return type based polymorphism. Related question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741047/polymorphic-scala-return-type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a little push and pull

```
trait Foo {
  def bar(a:String): String
  def bar(a:String)(implicit di: DummyImplicit): Int
}

class F extends Foo {
  def bar(a: String): String = "Hello"
  def bar(a: String)(implicit di: DummyImplicit): Int = 1
}

object Demo extends App {
  val f = new F()
  val s: String = f.bar("x")
  val i: Int = f.bar("x")
  println(s)
  println(i)
}
```

you can tweak it, using a `DummyImplicit` (to get around "Method is defined twice") and explicit typing (to pick one of the methods).

Answer (score 6):

On the JVM the return type of a method is not a part of a method signature. You have to give different method names or parameters. From Oracle [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html):

> Definition: Two of the components of a method declaration comprise the
>   method signature—the method's name and the parameter types.

What you are tryng to do is called Method overloading and Oracle says the following:

> The compiler does not consider return type when differentiating
>   methods, so you cannot declare two methods with the same signature
>   even if they have a different return type.

Cause Scala also compiles to JVM byte code, rules are the same

Comment: Strictly speaking, the JVM doesn't prevent this. At the JVM level, the return type *is* part of the method signature, so you could create two methods with the same name and parameter types but different return types (at the bytecode level at least). Java doesn't support this, however (there's no mechanism to distinguish between them), and Scala typically avoids breaking Java interoperability more than it has to.

Answer (score 3):

I can't really tell why it would be useful, but you could do this:

```
scala> object Foo {
     | trait BarImpl[T] { def apply(str: String): T }
     | implicit object barInt extends BarImpl[Int] { def apply(str: String) = 1 }
     | implicit object barBoolean extends BarImpl[Boolean] { def apply(str: String) = true }
     | def bar[T](str: String)(implicit impl: BarImpl[T]) = impl(str)
     | }
defined module Foo

scala> Foo.bar[Int]("asdf")
res8: Int = 1

scala> Foo.bar[Boolean]("asdf")
res9: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 2):

From wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading

```
Rules in function overloading

* The overloaded function must differ either by the arity or data types.
* The same function name is used for various instances of function call.
```

Only having different return types does not count as function overloading, and is not allowed.