# Polymorphic scala return type in recursive functions

Tags: scala, recursion, type-systems

I have a tree structure:

```
sealed trait Tree
case class Node(l: Tree, r: Tree) extends Tree
case class Leaf(n: Int) extends Tree
```

And a function that modifies the tree:

```
def scale(n: Int, tree: Tree): Tree = tree match {
  case l: Leaf => Leaf(l.n * n)
  case Node(l, r) => Node(scale(n, l), scale(n, r))
}
```

What should be the signature of the method above in order to return the appropriate subtype of Tree, and make the following line compile ?

```
scale(100, Leaf(1)).n // DOES NOT COMPILE
```

The closest answer I found so far is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741047/polymorphic-scala-return-type) and talks about [F-Bounded Quantification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification). But I can't find a way to apply it to recursive structures such a as trees! Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "appropriate subtype of Tree". My guess would be to make `def scale(n: Int, tree: Tree): Either[Tree,Node]` and change the `Leaf` and `Node` values to `Right(Leaf(...))` and `Left(Node(...))`. With this approach even the pattern match could be eliminated the in the argument is also an Either.

Comment: I think there is no way to determine result type of `scale` from input parameters in compile time. But why bother, you can use pattern matching on result of scale to get n, it's a common practice. `Either[Leaf, Node]` will not bring anything new because you will match on Left/Right instead which is just a redundant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from OOP and overriding, here is another solution:

You can actually define a type-class `Scaler` that represents a function from `(T, Int)` to `T` where `T` is a subtype of `Tree`. In the companion object of `Scaler` you can then define the corresponding implicits which will do the actual work. The static type of the return value follows from the definition of the type-class. Note that I extended your definition of `Node` with two generic parameters. There may be an alternative by using abstract types instead. This is left as an exercise to the reader :)

Well, here we go:

```
import language.implicitConversions

sealed trait Tree
case class Node[L <: Tree, R <: Tree](l: L, r: R) extends Tree
case class Leaf(n: Int) extends Tree

trait Scaler[T <: Tree] extends ((T, Int) => T)

object Scaler {
  implicit object scalesLeafs extends Scaler[Leaf] {
    def apply(l: Leaf, s: Int) =
      Leaf(l.n * s)
  }

  implicit def scalesNodes[L <: Tree: Scaler, R <: Tree: Scaler] = new Scaler[Node[L,R]] {
    val ls = implicitly[Scaler[L]]
    val rs = implicitly[Scaler[R]]

    def apply(n: Node[L,R], s: Int) =
      Node(ls(n.l, s), rs(n.r, s))
  }
}

object demo extends App {
  def scale[T <: Tree](t: T, s: Int)(implicit ev: Scaler[T]): T =
    ev(t, s)

  val check1 = scale(Leaf(3), 5)
  val check2 = scale(Node(Leaf(3), Leaf(7)), 5)

  Console println check1.n
  Console println check2.l.n
  Console println check2.r.n
}
```

**EDIT**: As a sidenote: If you have a tree invariant like all right-hand side leafs are greater or equal than the ones on the left-hand side, you might want to consider implementing scale in terms of mapping over the tree and thereby effecively creating a new tree, because scaling with negative numbers could violate the invariant.

Answer (score 2):

In scala there are often two options to define a function for a type. One is more functional (with pattern-matching like you did) the other one is more object oriented.

Unfortunately i have no solution for the version with pattern-matching (although i would be interested in one). But I have a solution for the more object oriented version, if this a an option for you:

```
sealed trait Tree {
  def scale(n: Int): Tree
}
case class Node(l: Tree, r: Tree) extends Tree {
  def scale(n: Int): Node = Node(l.scale(n), r.scale(n))
}
case class Leaf(n: Int) extends Tree {
  def scale(m: Int): Leaf = Leaf(n * m) 
}

Leaf(1).scale(100).n // does compile.
```

This solution is based on the fact that the return type of a method is covariant, so the return type in the implementation of `scale` in `Node` and `Leaf` can be a subtype of the return type of the abstract method `scale` in `Tree`.