# In Scala, Refer to Subclass in Abstract Super Class

Tags: scala, inheritance, implicit, play-json

Is there a way for the `this` keyword in a super class to refer to that class's subclass? Specifically, I am trying to do the following (the Json refers to Play's Json library):

```
abstract class A() {
  def toJson[T](implicit writes: Writes[T]): JsValue = Json.toJson(this)
}

case class B(myProperty: String) extends A
object B { implicit val bFormat = Json.format[B] }
```

This gives the error `No Json serializer found for type A. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.`. So it's saying it can't serialize an object of type `A`, which makes sense. The goal, however, is for the `this` in `Json.toJson(this)` to refer to the subclass (which, in this instance, is `B`).

Is there any way to accomplish this? If not, is there any other way I can implement the `Json.toJson(...)` method in the superclass without having to implement in the subclass (and all other subclasses of `A`)?

Comment: You can use F-Bounded polymorphism: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741047/polymorphic-scala-return-type

Comment: I would recommend using typeclasses instead. E.g. http://argonaut.io/doc/codec/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common trick to refer to the current subclass from the parent, is to use [F-bounded polymorphism](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded):

```
// Here `T` refers to the type of the current subclass
abstract class A[T <: A[T]]() { 
  this: T =>
  def toJson(implicit writes: Writes[T]): JsValue = Json.toJson(this)
}

// We have to specify the current subclass in `extends A[B]`
case class B(myProperty: String) extends A[B]
object B { implicit val bFormat = Json.format[B] }

println(B("foo").toJson)
```

This won't allow you to call `toJson` for any generic `A` though:

```
val a: A[_] = B("foo")
println(a.toJson)      // Doesn't compile with: 
                       //   No Json serializer found for type _$1. 
                       //   Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
```

To fix this you would have to save `Writes` for the subtype at the point of object creation:

```
abstract class A[T <: A[T]](implicit writes: Writes[T]) { 
  this: T =>
  def toJson: JsValue = Json.toJson(this)
}
```

Or alternatively using the [context bound](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-and-view-bounds.html#what-is-a-context-bound) notation:

```
abstract class A[T <: A[T] : Writes] { 
  this: T =>
  def toJson: JsValue = Json.toJson(this)
}
```

And since this F-bounded polymorphism thing is just an implementation detail and always refering to a generic `A` as `A[_]` is quite boilerplate-y, you can move this code to an intermediate `abstract class`.

So a full example looks like this:

```
abstract class A() {
  def toJson: JsValue
}

abstract class AImpl[T <: AImpl[T] : Writes] extends A { 
  this: T =>
  def toJson: JsValue = Json.toJson(this)
}

case class B(myProperty: String) extends AImpl[B]
object B { implicit val bFormat: Format[B] = Json.format[B] }

val a: A = B("foo")
println(a.toJson)
```

Comment: Why are `A` and `AImpl` abstract classes instead of traits?

Comment: @PimVerkerk OP had an abstract class. Also while `A` can easily be a trait, it's more convenient to implement `AImpl` as an abstract class to have it take an implicit argument. Making `AImpl` a trait would require manually creating this implicit `Writes` argument in every subclass.

Comment: Thank you. Something interesting is that this won't compile without explicitly setting the type of the `bFormat` property. As in, `implicit val bFormat = Json.format[B]` won't compile. Do you know why that is the case? Why can its type not be inferred from the `Json.format[B]` expression?

Comment: @socom1880 I can't find the links now, but basically it's an old bug/feature (it won't be fixed), that in some cases you have to either specify the implicit value before the class itself (i.e. put the companion object before its class), or explicitly specify the type of the implicit like in my example (or both at once).

Comment: Wow you're right, putting the companion object before the case class solves that issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not sure if this deserves its own question, but is there a way to avoid repeating `implicit val bFormat = Json.format[B]` in the companion object for each subclass of `A`? It seems like it's in the realm of possibilities given this concept of `F-bounded polymorphism`, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @socom1880 I don't know of any simple way to avoid it. Play Json generates `Format`/`Writes` implementations using macros which look up an `apply` and `unapply` functions in the companion object, and you can't really provide them in a general way. Just a guess, but maybe something from shapeless would work, like in https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/alacarte.scala But I usually just consider those things as unavoidable boilerplate and just write them out. You could try asking a separate question about this.